# Change cachable content

Tags: html, apache, caching

How can I change cachable content so that the user will immediately get the refreshed version?

I'll give an example: I have a .css file that is cachable for 2 weeks, so even if I change it, users will still get the old version, unless the press F5.

There are a few solutions, that I know of, but none are perfect:

- Changing the filename (from main.css to main2.css).
- Adding a unique URL parameter (like main.css?v=1).

I think that this could somehow be solved using apache eTags and I tried once with that but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best bet is to use the second option: add a parameter to the URL. So instead of writing `css/main.css`, just write `css/main.css?v=1` and then increment the `v` (as in version) parameter. I see it used all the time.

Sometimes a timestamp is added instead of the version, but be careful not to change this timestamp with every access to the page, as that would result in users never using their cache.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is way off, but doesn't bouncing apache clear its cache?

Something like: `/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful` perhaps?

Better yet, are you using apache itself for caching, or something else like squid?

I run apache 'normally', and when I make changes to css or other files (outside of scripts), just loading the page in my browser (like by clicking the "home" button), the *browser* shows the old version. Sometimes this is true even when I press <kbd>F5</kbd>. The only way I know to force the browser to *truly* reload is with <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-R</kbd> (on Windows) or <kbd>Cmd-Shift-R</kbd> (Mac OS).

Comment: This is not a viable solution for me, why should I restart apache just for this? Also, I'm on a shared server, so that's out of the question.

Comment: The problem is also that I cannot tell all the visitors to the site to Ctrl-Shift-R, because I've changed the styles.

Comment: @duality_ - if you can't make your users press refresh, and you can't bounce apache to clear its cache (though the user's browser cache may still be hampering you), then I'm not sure what to suggest